# Download a picture file from internet, Java on Android working in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio, download

I would like to create a very simple App with AndroidStudio to download an image file from the internet, but it just won't work at all. I've tried everything, checked the code, looked up similar questions on the internet, and tried with all sorts of picture sizes and formats. But I always get the error message at the bottom of the code.  Here is the code:

And Second question: How could I rewrite this very same code, but with the help of an IntentService class?   The answer to either one of these questions would be very appreciated.

```
    try{
        URL fileurl = new URL(urlstring);
        URLConnection urlConnection = fileurl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), 9200);
        File downloadordner = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");
        if(!downloadordner.exists()){
            downloadordner.mkdirs();
        }
        File downloadedFile = new File(downloadordner, "myFirstProject" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
        OutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
            outputstream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        outputstream.flush();
        outputstream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();



        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE I ALWAYS KEEP GETTING!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

The "Download" String is the name of the directory in the smartphone the the picture should me stored in! I would be very glad and grateful if someone could point me out what leads to this error message! Thanx :)

Comment: Can you share what error is reported?

Comment: Does the error occur on the Android device, or in the Android emulator?

Comment: The Error is the message I set as a String in the next to last line of the code.

Comment: The error occur in the emulator, I'm not testing it on the device yet.

Comment: Could you please add the error to your question please

Comment: I stecify myself the error message on the Toast Object, in the next to last line of the code. Here I put "THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE I ALWAYS KEEP GETTING!"